# Is it possible to send a raw UDP packet directly from the browser to an ip/port?

Tags: javascript, networking, web, webrtc

I've been told WebRTC, in particular data channels, allow one to use UDP on the browser. From looking at some documentation, though, I wasn't able to determine how to do the simple task of sending a raw UDP packet to a specific IP/port (possibly of a server that isn't aware of web at all).

Is it possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Not with WebRTC, no. The closest you can do is create a data channel, which uses SCTP over UDP (assuming the endpoints are able to be connect over UDP directly).

One reason WebRTC went with SCTP data channels is because there's a need for congestion control, to prevent applications from generating too much UDP traffic and working badly in parallel with TCP, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not directly through a web app, but you can build a Chrome app/extension to do so.

See examples:

1. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network
2. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/udp.

Comment: Apparently UDP sockets are not possible in extensions anymore. It was possible at one point, but they disabled it due to security concerns -- restricting it only to Chrome apps, which are being ended/phased-out now as well. :/